# Developing an app with Android Studio, is there any way I can upload an image to a hosting server?

Tags: android, image, host

I'm using Android Studio to develop an application. I'd like to ask the user of the app to make a photo or upload an image of his device, and I'd like to know if there's any way that I can take this file, upload it to a hosting server and get the URL of the hosted image.

Thanks!

Comment: This is probably not a quesiton suited for SO since it it not programming related. Try superuser instead.

Answer (score 0):

You'll basically need to use the `Http` and `File` classes that Android provides, `decode` the image file from camera when the result is returned. Then `AsyncTask` to process the uploading work.

This should help

> **Tutorial:** http://www.codepool.biz/tech-frontier/android/take-a-photo-from-android-camera-and-upload-it-to-a-remote-php-server.html
>
> **Source Code:** https://github.com/DynamsoftRD/JavaHTTPUpload